# Add Cookie to jQuery Sidr

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to add a cookie to my jQuery call for the plugin called [Sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)

I want the slide to stay open when toggled and add a cookie to remember the state.

e.g.

```
$('#simple-menu').sidr({
side: 'left' // By default
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this please? the following are the `open` and `close` calls.

```
//close
$.sidr('close', 'sidr-main');

// Open
$.sidr('open', 'sidr-main');
```

I have edited the example code i link in the comment and have so far tried editing it but stuck at the moment. grrr

```
$('#simple-menu').sidr({
    side: 'left' // By default
});

// Open / Close Panel According to Cookie //    
if ($.cookie('panel') == 'open'){    
    $.sidr('open', 'sidr');
} else {
    $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
}     

$('#aaa').click(function(){     
    $('#sidr').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie('panel', 'closed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('panel', 'open');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before opening and closing you will want to set a cookie making sure to give it a long enough expiration date.

Then when you instantiate the sidr on a new page load you can check for the existence of a cookie and depending on its value you can either instantiate your sidr open or closed.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Hi Rob, i have found a demo which looks like i could edit but not sure if its right for what i need? [http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK)

Comment: I've added a part edited code into my post but not sure what to do with the second part?

Comment: I see you have used the jQuery Cookie plugin.  You needed to add an expiry rather than the default which just lasts the session which doesn't persist between page loads.  I have added that to the update fiddle and it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/599/